# Espresso Testing with JSON Objects

Tags: android, json, android-espresso

I am working on test cases for an Android applications. I am using Espresso for automated ui testing. In one of my activities, I am using an Array Adapter to manage a ListView. Specifically, it works with a list of JSON Objects. In Espresso, I am trying to match a particular list element using the OnData method.

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(JSONObject.class)), hasEntry(equalTo("title"), is("FIU-MMC Blood Drive"))))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.homeListViewList)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

The test case crashes because it cannot find a matching element. However, the stack trace clearly shows the element that I am trying to find with "title" as the key and "FIU-MMC Blood Drive" as the value:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No data found matching: (is an instance of org.json.JSONObject and map containing ["title"->is "FIU-MMC Blood Drive"]) contained values: <[Data: {"bloodDriveId":1,"title":"FIU-MMC Blood Drive","description":"We need blood due to the high frequency of accidents in the area.","startTime":"2015-09-23","endTime":"2015-12-23","address":"1234 FIU Way"} (class: org.json.JSONObject) token: 0 ...
```

I have no idea why it is saying that it cannot find it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
onData(new BoundedMatcher<Object, JSONObject>(JSONObject.class) {
    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("Matching to JSONObject");
    }

    @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            return "FIU-MMC Blood Drive".equals(jsonObject.getString("title"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return false;
        }
    } }).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.homeListViewList)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```